# What tools can be used for testing WCF SOAP services with X.509 authentication?

Tags: wcf, soap, automated-tests, soa, x509

Can anyone recommend a tool to help with the manual and automated testing of WCF SOAP 1.2 services that use X.509 certificates for authentication?

I've tried [WCFStorm](http://www.wcfstorm.com) - and while it is reasonably close to what I need, it doesn't support X.509 authentication. [SoapPanda](http://www.soappanda.com/) (though free - my favourite price) didn't seem able to do anything WCFStorm couldn't do and was a lot more clunky.

[SoapSonar](http://www.crosschecknet.com/products/soapsonar.php) looks good on the website - does anyone have experience with this? I've asked the IT people at my company to procure me a demo version to test, but it usually takes a long time for them to get round to installing it on my development machine.

Edit: I have written automated tests for my own quality control, however I need to be able to hand over my SOA to be tested by our test team - and they need a UI to test it via as they aren't so technical. I *really* don't want to have to build and maintain a UI for every service.

Any experience with any similar tools will be of interest to me.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'll answer my own question - maybe it will help someone one day - though judging by the lack of interest I'm guessing that this is an obscure case.

I've test-driven SoapSonar and it does indeed fit the bill. It has full support for X.509 certificate authentication. It's a bit on the pricey side, but it also has support for load testing and security testing.

It'll be a pretty good fit in my organisation as the testers can create test cases using SoapSonar independently of developers. They can manage suites of tests and ensure that there is no regression. So the testing effort should scale as we role out more and more services.

The tester works through a UI to create the test cases without needing any programming knowledge which is handy.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [link text](http://www.tellagostudios.com/products/so-aware%E2%84%A2)SO-Aware.  It is a Service Repository, the helps to manage, track, discover, test your services.  It was built with WCF Services in mind, but works with other services.

For full disclosure, I'm the CTO of Tellago Studios, who developed SO-Aware, so I am bias, but I'm also interested in feedback.  If you are looking for a pure client side service testing tool that can work with secured services, please feel free to contact me directly ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have used Soap Sonar for a number of years in testing web services.  However I have only used the free version and have not tested it with WCF.  I am getting ready to test it on a newly constructed WCF service hopefully it will work.

Comment: We have bought Soap Sonar, and it does work with WCF. We're fairly happy with it. Though it isn't cheap.